# If $T$ injective or $T$ surjective, what is the composition $T^\ast T$? (where $T^\ast$ denotes adjoint of linear map $T$)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V \to W$ be a linear transformation between inner product spaces. Then $T^\ast: W \to V$ denotes the linear transformation with the property that for every $v \in V$ and $w \in W$, $$\langle T(v),w \rangle = \langle v, T^\ast(w) \rangle.$$ We call $T^\ast$ the adjoint of $T:V \to W$.

$\cdot$ If $T$ is injective is $T^\ast T$ injective (or possibly a bijection)?

$\cdot$ If $T$ is surjective is $T T^\ast$ surjective (or a bijection)?

How can we prove this? Any pointers in the right direction appreciated.

Comment: As also pointed out by others, the adjoint goes from $W^*$ to $V^*$. How do you propose to compose them? With matrices the distinction can be blurred and you can identify the dual space, albeit non-canonically. Please clarify. As you see the answer depends...

Answer (score 2):

Consider the left-shift operator on $\ell^2$
$$
T((x_n)) = (x_2,x_3,\ldots)
$$
Then
$$
T^{\ast}((x_n)) = (0,x_1,x_2,\ldots)
$$
Then $T$ is surjective, and
$$
T^{\ast}T((x_n)) = (0,x_2,x_3,\ldots)
$$
Hence, $T^{\ast}T$ is neither injective nor surjective.

Comment: What does $T^*$ mean in this question?

Comment: @Arashium: As mentioned by the OP, it is the adjoint of $T$.

Comment: @Shalop: Agreed, but this is standard convention. Furthermore, the compostion $T^{\ast}T$ only makes sense under this identification. Else, the OP's question does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

start with

$$T^*\times T=T\times T^*=\det(T) I_n$$

Comment: And when the space is infinite-dimensional??

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Then I have no idea :D

Comment: Besides, it looks like you thought of the [adjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) rather than the adjoint.

Comment: @DanielFischer How do you define adjoint?

Comment: For inner product spaces, the adjoint of $T\colon V \to W$ is the linear operator $T^{\ast}\colon W \to V$ characterised by the identity $\langle T(v), w\rangle_W = \langle v, T^{\ast}(w)\rangle_V$ for all $v\in V$ and $w\in W$.